Eliminar filas con NA en todas las columnas numéricas dataframe R
Tengo un dataframe con varias columnas, la primera contiene los identificadores y las siguientes valores numéricos. Quiero eliminar las filas que cumplen con la condición de tener NA en todas sus columnas numéricas.
He intentado utilizar la función complete.cases() para eliminar las filas con NA, pero elimina todas las filas con al menos un NA y obtengo un dataframe con solo filas con valores numéricos.
df <- data.frame(
  columna1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  columna2 = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA),
  columna3 = c(6, 7, NA, 9, NA),
  columna4 = c(11, 12, 13, 14, NA),
  columna5 = c(21, 22, 23, 24, NA)
)

 columna1 columna2 columna3 columna4 columna5
1        A        1        6       11       21
2        B        2        7       12       22
3        C        3       NA       13       23
4        D       NA        9       14       24
5        E       NA       NA       NA       NA

df2 <- df[complete.cases(df), ]

columna1 columna2 columna3 columna4 columna5
1        A        1        6       11       21
2        B        2        7       12       22


El df que espero sería así:
 columna1 columna2 columna3 columna4 columna5
1        A        1        6       11       21
2        B        2        7       12       22
3        C        3       NA       13       23
4        D       NA        9       14       24


La siguiente opción no es la óptima pero puede servirte de utilidad. Para ello, suponemos que conoces el número de columnas a analizar y que están seguidas; de no ser así se puede modificar.
En este caso, calculamos en cada fila cuántos NA existen dentro de lo que conocemos como variables numéricas (todas las columnas menos la primera). Eliminamos las filas para las que dicha cantidad es exactamente 4 (el número de columnas que se está evaluando).
df <- df[apply(df[,-1],1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))!=4,]


Podés usar rowSums + is.na para crear un vector de selección de filas:
> df[rowSums(is.na(df[, -1])) != 4, ]
  columna1 columna2 columna3 columna4 columna5
1        A        1        6       11       21
2        B        2        7       12       22
3        C        3       NA       13       23
4        D       NA        9       14       24

Si preferís usar apply sin hacer el conteo para la comparación lógica, entonces se podría reemplazar la suma por all:
> df[!apply(is.na(df), 1, all), ]
  columna1 columna2 columna3 columna4 columna5
1        A        1        6       11       21
2        B        2        7       12       22
3        C        3       NA       13       23
4        D       NA        9       14       24

Esta última propuesta asume que la primer columna no contiene NA, si pudiera contener NA entonces reemplazar df por df[,-1]
Finalmente, si querés una versión al estilo tidyverse:
  library(dplyr)
  df %>% 
    filter(!if_all(where(is.numeric), ~is.na(.)))
  columna1 columna2 columna3 columna4 columna5
1        A        1        6       11       21
2        B        2        7       12       22
3        C        3       NA       13       23
4        D       NA        9       14       24

O en una sola línea: filter(df, !if_all(where(is.numeric), ~is.na(.)))

Una forma bien genérica que contempla las dos condiciones dadas para quitar filas:

Solo considerar columnas numéricas
Que todos los valores sean NA


df[apply(!is.na(df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)]), 1, any), ]

